# How to increase the unit increase/decrease for regression coefficients

Tags: regression

Hi everyone reading this question. I would like to model cox regression for reliability analysis in SAS. The continuous covariates' parameter estimates are very small for one unit increase or decrease in those covariates (i.e, if x increases one unit then beta2 would increase 0.0037%). I would like to increase the x unit from one unit to 1000 or 10000 in order for the parameter estimates to be more pronounced (i.e, if x increases 1000 units then beta2 would increase 3.7%). I would be grateful if anyone could give me direction on how to do it? I mean, the unit increase/decrease should be 1000 or 10000 instead of one unit for the covariates I specify this. It is not important the direction to be SAS specific, I can handle that. It would be nice if the direction includes a reference to read furthermore about this. I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

If, for the sake of argument, your predictor is measured in millimetres try measuring it in metres instead or even kilometres. So to express that mathematically divide your current value by some suitable constant like 1000 or $10^6$. You can still do this for any variable even if it does not have named units so you often see things expressed per 1000s of dollars rather than per dollar or per 100000 person years to get sensible values.

I do not use SAS but I am sure it can do this and anyway you did not ask for programming advice.